# Implement multilayer perceptron with two hidden layers via derivatives

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I am trying to implement a multilayer perceptron with two hidden layers to predict diabetes in an Indian tribe as a project from the book "Neural Network Projects with Python." The code from the book comes from https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Neural-Network-Projects-with-Python/tree/master/Chapter02, but I would like to implement it by taking derivatives and such. The input layer has 8 neurons, the first hidden layer has 32 neurons, the second hidden layer has 16 neurons, and the output layer is one neuron. ReLU is used to active each hidden layer and sigmoid is used for the output layer. I keep getting RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp about 80% of the time that I run the code after the first backprop. I don't think it's exactly right. The book achieved 78% test accuracy using the test dataset in only 200 epochs using the Keras library, but my code gets about 70% when it doesn't throw the RuntimeWarning in 2000 epochs, so I think there's something wrong with my derivatives. Could someone help me out? The data comes from Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

df = pd.read_csv("diabetes.csv")

def preprocess(df):

    df["Glucose"] = df["Glucose"].replace(0, np.nan)
    df["Glucose"] = df["Glucose"].fillna(df["Glucose"].mean())
    df["BloodPressure"] = df["BloodPressure"].replace(0, np.nan)
    df["BloodPressure"] = df["BloodPressure"].fillna(df["BloodPressure"].mean())
    df["SkinThickness"] = df["SkinThickness"].replace(0, np.nan)
    df["SkinThickness"] = df["SkinThickness"].fillna(df["SkinThickness"].mean())
    df["Insulin"] = df["Insulin"].replace(0, np.nan)
    df["Insulin"] = df["Insulin"].fillna(df["Insulin"].mean())
    df["BMI"] = df["BMI"].replace(0, np.nan)
    df["BMI"] = df["BMI"].fillna(df["BMI"].mean())

    df_scaled = preprocessing.scale(df)
    df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(df_scaled, columns = df.columns)
    df_scaled["Outcome"] = df["Outcome"]
    return df_scaled

df = preprocess(df)

X = df.loc[:, df.columns != "Outcome"]
y = df.loc[:, "Outcome"]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)
y_train = np.array(y_train)[:, np.newaxis]
y_test = np.array(y_test)[:, np.newaxis]

def relu(x):
    if x<0:
        return 0
    return x

relu = np.vectorize(relu)

def relu_derivative(x):
    dx = 0
    if (x > 0):
        dx = 1
    return dx

relu_derivative = np.vectorize(relu_derivative)

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return x * (1-x)

class MultilayerPerceptron:
    def __init__(self, X, y):
        self.input = X
        self.y = y
        self.weights1 = np.random.rand(8, 32)
        self.bias1 = np.zeros([1, 32])
        self.weights2 = np.random.rand(32, 16)
        self.bias2 = np.zeros([1, 16])
        self.weights3 = np.random.rand(16, 1)
        self.bias3 = np.zeros([1, 1])

    def feedforward(self):
        self.Z1 = np.dot(self.input, self.weights1) + np.repeat(self.bias1, self.input.shape[0], 0)
        self.A1 = relu(self.Z1)
        self.Z2 = np.dot(self.A1, self.weights2) + np.repeat(self.bias2, self.input.shape[0], 0)
        self.A2 = relu(self.Z2)
        self.Z3 = np.dot(self.A2, self.weights3) + np.repeat(self.bias3, self.input.shape[0], 0)
        self.output = sigmoid(self.Z3)

    def backprop(self):
        d_weights3 = np.dot(self.A2.T, sigmoid_derivative(self.output) * 2 * (self.output - self.y))
        d_bias3 = np.mean(sigmoid_derivative(self.output) * 2 * (self.output - self.y), 0)[:, np.newaxis].T
        d_weights2 = np.dot(self.A1.T, relu_derivative(self.Z2) * np.dot(sigmoid_derivative(self.output) * 2 * (self.output - self.y), self.weights3.T))
        d_bias2 = np.mean(relu_derivative(self.Z2) * np.dot(sigmoid_derivative(self.output) * 2 * (self.output - self.y), self.weights3.T), 0)[:, np.newaxis].T
        x = np.dot(relu_derivative(self.Z2) * np.repeat(self.weights3.T, self.input.shape[0], 0), self.weights2.T) * np.repeat(sigmoid_derivative(self.output) * 2 * (self.output - self.y), 32, 1)
        d_weights1 = np.dot(self.input.T, relu_derivative(self.Z1) * x)
        d_bias1 = np.mean(relu_derivative(self.Z1) * x, 0)[:, np.newaxis].T

        lr = 0.1
        self.weights3 = self.weights3 - lr * d_weights3
        self.bias3 = self.bias3 - lr * d_bias3
        self.weights2 = self.weights2 - lr * d_weights2
        self.bias2 = self.bias2 - lr * d_bias2
        self.weights1 = self.weights1 - lr * d_weights1
        self.bias1 = self.bias1 - lr * d_bias1


    def predict(self, x):
        x1 = np.array((x.loc[:, "Pregnancies"] - np.mean(self.input.loc[:, "Pregnancies"], 0)) / np.std(self.input.loc[:, "Pregnancies"]))[:, np.newaxis]
        x2 = np.array((x.loc[:, "Glucose"] - np.mean(self.input.loc[:, "Glucose"], 0)) / np.std(self.input.loc[:, "Glucose"]))[:, np.newaxis]
        x3 = np.array((x.loc[:, "BloodPressure"] - np.mean(self.input.loc[:, "BloodPressure"], 0)) / np.std(self.input.loc[:, "BloodPressure"]))[:, np.newaxis]
        x4 = np.array((x.loc[:, "SkinThickness"] - np.mean(self.input.loc[:, "SkinThickness"], 0)) / np.std(self.input.loc[:, "SkinThickness"]))[:, np.newaxis]
        x5 = np.array((x.loc[:, "Insulin"] - np.mean(self.input.loc[:, "Insulin"], 0)) / np.std(self.input.loc[:, "Insulin"]))[:, np.newaxis]
        x6 = np.array((x.loc[:, "BMI"] - np.mean(self.input.loc[:, "BMI"], 0)) / np.std(self.input.loc[:, "BMI"]))[:, np.newaxis]
        x7 = np.array((x.loc[:, "DiabetesPedigreeFunction"] - np.mean(self.input.loc[:, "DiabetesPedigreeFunction"], 0)) / np.std(self.input.loc[:, "DiabetesPedigreeFunction"]))[:, np.newaxis]
        x8 = np.array((x.loc[:, "Age"] - np.mean(self.input.loc[:, "Age"], 0)) / np.std(self.input.loc[:, "Age"]))[:, np.newaxis]
        x = np.concatenate((x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8), 1)
        Z1 = np.dot(x, self.weights1) + np.repeat(self.bias1, x.shape[0], 0)
        A1 = relu(Z1)
        Z2 = np.dot(A1, self.weights2) + np.repeat(self.bias2, x.shape[0], 0)
        A2 = relu(Z2)
        Z3 = np.dot(A2, self.weights3) + np.repeat(self.bias3, x.shape[0], 0)
        return np.round(sigmoid(Z3))

mlp = MultilayerPerceptron(X_train, y_train)

for i in range(2000):
    mlp.feedforward()
    mlp.backprop()

print(confusion_matrix(y_test, mlp.predict(X_test)))

def accuracy(actual, predicted):
    count = 0
    for i in range(actual.shape[0]):
        if actual[i, 0] == predicted[i, 0]:
            count = count+1
    return count / actual.shape[0]

print(accuracy(y_test, mlp.predict(X_test)))
```

Comment: Adjusting the learning rate from 0.1 to 0.0005 and the epochs from 2000 to 3000 got rid of the RuntimeWarning: Overflow encountered in exp and increased the accuracy from about 0.70 (when it worked) to 0.74 - 0.78 ish all the time, I guess I just needed to tune these two hyperparameters?

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant. It seems that your `sigmoid_derivative` is wrong. It should be `sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))`, right?